# Как исправить ошибку в Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

вопросик по gulp!настраиваю плагин imagemin при проверке выдает ошибку почему то!что я не так делаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIqgZ.jpg): [Мой Gulp](https://codepen.io/coderunner909/pen/qBOggbe)

```
 imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
```

Comment: не уверен, что такое парсится неправильно, но все же попробуйте убрать лишнюю запятую в `path.watch.img`

Comment: какую где именно?

Comment: @verstak44444 Строка 23, лишняя запятая перед gif